# ordering the hydrophilicity of some polymers

Tags: polymers, polarity, surface-chemistry, surfactants

I need to compare the hydrophilicity of those materials to compare contact angles of water with those materials' surfaces for surface tension measurement. Materials are:

PTFE (Teflon), PVC, PS, PVDF, Si-Wafer-Si-SiO$_x$, Parafilm and PMMA

Ordering the polarity can also work. Where can I found such a comparison? Can someone help me with the ordering. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎